# images are not lining up when using percentage-based values

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to line up 2 images using inline-block property in css.
when using px based values it's working correctly but I need to make the page fitting to the whole screen, so when I use percentage based values the second image keeps showing below the first one. what could I do?
here's my html code:

```html
<div>
        <figure id="aref">
            <img id="lot" src=".." alt="look">
            <figcaption>xxx</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img id="cat" src=".." alt="oh no">
            <figcaption>meow</figcaption>
        </figure>
</div>
```

my css code:

```css
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#lot {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cat {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***I need to make the page fitting to the whole screen***?

Comment: @Kameron u know when we want the page to look the same on different screen sizes

Comment: You could say "I want images to be responsive when resizing the browser" what size are your images?? width and height?